# Building Scala JAR file Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My build.sbt file has  (Im using IntelliJ)

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
resolvers  += "MavenRepository" at "http://central.maven.org/maven2"
resolvers += "spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"
    Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion )
}
```

Im trying to build a JAR and deploy it into Spark. I have issued following commands

```
sbt compile

sbt assembly
```

Compilation was successful but assembly failed with following error message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Please add any Spark dependencies by supplying the sparkVersion and sparkComponents. Please remove: org.apache.spark:spark-core:2.2.1
```

I tried to add `"provided"` to keep it out that time compilation itself fails as `"provided"` key word
doesnt include those JARs

What is the mistake am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to add plugin and dependencies for assembly which will create jar for you.

In plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
```

Add this in your `build.sbt`

```
mainClass := Some("name of jar")
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

You can refer my [github](https://github.com/mahesh2492/spark-on-mesos) to create jar and deploy

Comment: It works !! what is xs, x and ps - is there any specific meaning for each?